# Link does not work unless it's set to absolute

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Not sure why, but none links over the images in my posts works unless it's set to `position: absolute;`

**Summary:**

- No problems with neither `src` or `href`
- The pointer cursor does not appear
- Nothing happens when clicking on the image
- The links works when I set `a` to `position: absolute;`, but then everything is misplaced and so on.

I have tried shortening it up to make it easier to debug.

**Shorten HTML**

```
<a href="#.jpg">
    <img src="#.jpg" alt="Alt text" width="1200" height="800">
</a>
```

**(Shortened) Complete HTML**

```
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="holder blacktext bildeserieholder">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 centertext">
                    <a href="#.jpg"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-512" src="#.jpg" alt="text" width="1200" height="800" /></a> 
                    <a href="#.jpg"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-513" src="#.jpg" alt="text" width="600" height="900" /></a> 
                    <a href="#.jpg"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-514" src="#.jpg" alt="text" width="1200" height="800" /></a> 
                    <a href="#.jpg"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-515" src="#.jpg" alt="text" width="1200" height="800" /></a> 
                    <a href="#.jpg"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-516" src="#.jpg" alt="text" width="600" height="900" /></a>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**I have tried:**

- Using `cursor: pointer` to the link attribute.
- Removing all `img classes`
- Removing all CSS on both images and links in Chrome Inspect Element

It's hard to find out where I have done something wrong, so I would really recommend checking out the page: http://goo.gl/DqXAlC

Maybe not relevant, but I will add this information anyways regarding what I am using:

- Wordpress
- Bootstrap
- Types (custom posts etc plugin)

The images are being uploaded with Types within each posts in a WYSIWYG editor called "bildeserie". In my single PHP I have the following which echos the images:

```
<?php echo(types_render_field( "bildeserie", array( 'raw' => true) )); ?>
```

Do you have a working solution or any ideas?

**Note:** The problem is with the images below the header and all the text.

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question. A) I'm not going to an unknown site and weed through the code to debug it, B) Once the problem is fixed then this question loses all value to future visitors if the code isn't here, and C) adding a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps *you* debug the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions:

```
.holder img {
  pointer-events: none;
 }
```

The above is disabling the link on the image, commenting it out will make everything work.

Second solution:

```
a {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

That also fixes your problem (by expanding the link to the dimensions of the image).

Comment: That was the solution. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you.

Comment: WordPress often adds styles to elements that you add. The first step to debugging stylistic stuff like this should just be to `inspect element` in your browser and tinker with it so you understand what WordPress has done! Just some advice for the future, happy coding

Comment: Thank you. I actually did that, but I couldn't find the error. I guess I was just too dull

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that the img has a size and the link does not have a size unless set to absolute. If the a doesn't have a size, you aren't clicking on the a you are clicking on the img, give the a a size and see what happens

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I was actually thinking about the same, but nothing changed when I changed `height` and `width`

Comment: CSS is not my strong suit. I know I have fixed this before, but I don't remember how. You may try both of them on relative and give the same HxW for the a and the img and see what that does for you

Comment: Thank you. The problem was solved by removing some other CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

You should disable this line in your style.css file:

```
.holder img {
pointer-events: none;
}
```